# Can "ad aliquid" mean "the same"?

Tags: meaning

Grimms' glossed German *[einschlägig](https://dwds.de/wb/dwb/einschl%C3%A4gig)* thus:

> *spectans, pertinens ad aliquid, bezüglich*

I was looking to understand what *einschlägig* means, which is only used in fixed expressions, and I'm afraid I didn't get very far, but if you have to ask (if the gloss isn't enlightening):

- For what it's worth, [W. Pfeifer](https://dwds.de/wb/einschl%C3%A4gig) and [de.wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einschl%C3%A4gig) agree, it can mean approximately: "for the same purpose, in the same matter".
- That is however not quite obvious from the older usage example in Grimm, nor from the glosses. Further elaboration is besides the point, though, cp. perhaps Grimms' entry at *[bezüglich](https://dwds.de/wb/dwb/bez%C3%BCglich)*.
- From en.wiktionary I can glean that *aliquid* is an inflected form of *aliquis* "something" ("other" + "what")
- Now it dawns on me that any sense of sameness might be conferred by the inflected construction with *ad*, as if "of one thing", "pertaining to quite something else."

Is that it?

What a shame, I was gonna run through a couple etymology notes about the same. I'll repost under the etymology tag pending confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ad aliquid" literally means "to something." So "spectans/pertinens ad aliquid" means "regarding/pertaining to something." In context it does mean "... to something previously mentioned or assumed to be known to the reader," i.e. "to the 'same' thing." The English Wiktionary says that einschlägig means 'relevant, pertinent, appropriate' and bezüglich means 'regarding, with respect to.'

Comment: I faintly remembervthat Italian [altri](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/altri) may mean "other" as well as "previous, last". Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

This question is based on a faulty premise in the interpretation of the definitions.

- DWDS's definition is: „zu dem Gebiet, Bereich gehörend, das Gebiet, den Bereich betreffend“ (belonging to the domain, pertaining to the domain)
- Pfeifer's definition is: „in Betracht kommend“ (coming into consideration)
- Wiktionary's definition is:  „zu einem bestimmten Gebiet, Bereich gehörend“ (belonging to a certain domain).

Neither contains anything that translates to “the same.”

It is true that German *einschlägig* must always refer to something mentioned or implied in context. But as none of the German definitions makes that explicit, so we cannot expect the Grimms' definition to make it explicit either.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found:

In the Lewis&Short you can find:

> *Ad aliquid esse*, in gram. lang., to refer or relate **to something else** ([Entry: Aliquis II, D](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/aliquis))

And then in [specto II B 1](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/specto):

> To look to a thing, as to an end or guide of action; hence, to have in view, bear in mind; to aim, strive, or endeavor after; to meditate; **to tend, incline, refer, pertain**, or have regard to a thing (freq. and class.; **syn.**: contendo, **pertineo**, tendo)

I would say that in *spectans, pertinens ad aliquid*:

- We have a synonymy *spectans/pertinens*.
- And then we have the *ad aliquid*, meaning "to something else".

I would translate *spectans, pertinens ad aliquid* as "looking to / refering to something else".

I don't see anything that could bring me to "the same".

Comment: L&S say that the main definition of aliquid is 'something (or other), anything,' as does https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/aliquis#Latin. The context has to show whether it means 'something already mentioned,' or 'something else' (with aliud implied). Several Latin dictionaries also use the abbreviations alqm (aliquem), alci (alicui), alqd (aliquid) etc. as meaning 'someone, something,' to show how to use a verb.

Comment: See the end of the Wiktionary entry for a long list of examples from Meissner and Auden's Latin phrasebook, in which aliquid etc. are written out.